# ranlib and static library

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile, x86-64

I am trying to link a static library that I created, but I get this error.

```
libmine.a: could not read symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one
```

I tried to do `ranlib libmine.a` but nothing changed, it still gives the same error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why not simply `ar czvf libmine.a *.o`? Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765240/could-not-read-symbols-archive-has-no-index-run-ranlib-to-add-one

Comment: What is the output of `nm libmine.a`?  I haven't run `ranlib` for about 15 years - it's no longer required as `ar` takes care of it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see the symbols in an archive, use nm.

```
nm -s libmine.a
```

<output>

The entry points to the subroutines should be labled "T" as in

```
00000000 T _sub1
00000019 T _sub2
```

What switches did you use in "ar" to make the static library? I usually use "ar -r" as in

```
ar -r libmine.a mine.o yours.o
```

If you are still having problems, add the "-s" option

```
ar -s -r libmine.a mine.o yours.o
```

Also, be sure that there are no other "libmine.a" files in the path, or make an explicit path to your "libmine.a". It is possible the linker is picking up a different "libmine.a".