# How do I strip symbols only from dependent libraries?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I'd like to ship `libfoo.a`, which is composed of `foo.o`--which in turn depends on `libVendorBar.a` and `libVendorZoo.a`.

When I link and generate my `libfoo.a` I notice that symbols in `libVendor*.a` are still public and visible for potential client applications to link against.

Due to many reasons outside of my control, I absolutely do not want 3rd party clients to be able to directly link against the vendor libraries.

How do I force gcc to resolve all libVendor symbols for libfoo and discard them, so that only symbols from libfoo are visible?

I'm not using any `LD_FLAGS` currently and everything is statically linked.

Comment: have you seen this https://linux.die.net/man/1/strip ?

Comment: `strip` doesn't do what I want even with `-K`.  It seems to discard something called the archive index from the static library.  [If I regenerate the index via `ranlib`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346240/ranlib-and-static-library), the linked binary is *super* strange, with every "branch and link" instruction jumping to itself and creating an infinite loop.  I spent half-a-day debugging the fallout of `strip` and `ranlib` before realizing that I'm doing something fundamentally wrong.  Surely there must be something within `gcc` that can do what I want?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851045/gcc-a-static-library-with-undefined-symbols what I'm looking for is the `-static` flag, which fully resolves all symbols.  I'm hoping this also means that gcc will be smart enough to discard most of the symbols.  I guess I'll update this post tomorrow if it works out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately static libraries do not have equivalent of `-fvisibility=hidden` used for shared libraries. You can achieve what you need with more work though:

- first link all necessary code into `foo.o`:

  ```
  ld -r foo.o -Lpath/to/vendor/libs -lBar -lZoo -o foo_linked.o
  ```

  This would allow you can to ship `libfoo.a` without vendor libs (vendor symbols are still present in it).
- Unfortunately you can't simply remove vendor symbols from library symtab (e.g. via `objcopy -L` and `strip --strip-symbol`) because linker will need them for relocation processing during final executable link. But you can at least rename them to something unreadable:

  ```
  for sym in all symbols you want to hide; do
    id=$(echo $sym | md5sum | awk '{print $1}')
    objcopy --redefine-sym $sym=f_$id foo_linked.o
  done
  ```

  Note however that this wouldn't stop motivated user from reverse engineering vendor's code.