# could not read symbols: Archive has no index

Tags: static-libraries, recompile, makefile

I must take care an old project and get stuck in it. It's a makefile project and I get the error *could not read symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one* when doing build.

I found an helpful link about this issue, [could not read symbols: Archive has no index; run ranlib to add one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765240/could-not-read-symbols-archive-has-no-index-run-ranlib-to-add-one?answertab=active#tab-top).

I tried *nm liboprt.a* command and get result *File format not recognized* for object files. 
I also tried *file planeoprt.o* and get the result *planeoprt.o: ELF 32-bit MSB relocatable, MIPS, MIPS-II version 1 (SYSV), not stripped*

The problem is I just have static library (.a) and object file (.o) so that I cannot follow their instructions to recompile the source code (.c).

Does someone help me come over this problem without recompiling source code?